# ASP.NET how to access User.Identity.IsAuthenticated in Aplication Request module?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-2.0, asp.net-2.0, form-authentication

I am using Form Authentication Method in ASP.Net and the problem is it only protect "*.aspx" files. I am trying to protect "*.php" files in "kcfinder" folder from unauthenticated users.

I implemeted this class in "App_Code" folder.

```
public class KCChecker
{
        public static void Process(HttpApplication Application)
    {
           HttpRequest Request = Application.Context.Request;
           HttpResponse Response = Application.Context.Response;
           string url = Request.Path.ToLower();
           if (url.IndexOf("/kcfinder/") == 0 && !HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
            Response.Redirect("/");
            }
        }
}
```

The problem is it always say "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." on `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`. I tried to change it to `Application.Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` but it still shows the same error.

Is there any way I can access User Object in this custom module's Process function?

Comment: Disclaimer - I don't have experience running PHP under IIS. However, IIS has certain types configured to be handled by Asp.Net, and I wouldn't expect php to be handled by Asp.Net, so Context would be null.

Comment: Context is not null. Request and Response of Context object are all working. ONLY Request.User is null.

Comment: So what does Request.IsAuthenticated return - true/false? Could it be that you have Anonymous Access enabled? Also I [found](http://forums.asp.net/t/1689878.aspx/1) this: runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"

Comment: Request.IsAuthenticated always return false. I just read that thread on ASP.NET forum. YES! Adding "<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />" allows me to access Application.Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated. Can you post your answer below? So that I can accept it? Cheers.

Comment: Oh no. I'm not sure it allows me to access that object but after adding that property, my form authenticaiton is protecting kcfinder folder. This is what I want and even the best solution than being handled by HttpHandler. Thanks.

Comment: Geeez. I got another issue. It not only protect PHP files, it protects EVERYTHING. My images inside kcfinder folder aren't showing unless I logged into CMS tool. :(

Comment: It is fine now. I just had to add "<location path="kcfinder/upload/images">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="*"/>
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>" to allow everyone to access images folder. Everything is perfect now. Thanks Michael.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your web.config file:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
```

Comment: I found one funny thing about Google Chrome. If the request file is .aspx, it looks fine and it redirects to login page but when it is .pdf or .jpg, it keeps trying like infinite loop but it is still protecting the resources. It works fine on all other browsers, except google chrome.

Answer (score 1):

[HttpApplication.PostAuthenticateRequest Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.postauthenticaterequest)

Add an event handler for PostAuthenticateRequest to your HttpModule and call your Process(HttpApplication) method from there.

```
public class AuthModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.PostAuthenticateRequest += new EventHandler(context_PostAuthenticateRequest);
    }

    public void Dispose() { }

    void context_PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var isAuthenticated = ((HttpApplication) sender).Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
    }
}
```

Comment: It still shows "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.". on "bool isAuthenticated = ((HttpApplication)sender).Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;"

Comment: Odd, what exactly is NULL?  Context.User?  It should be defined at that point in the ASP.NET life cycle.

Comment: Best answer for this problem!